# Compress the image without sacrificing its quality c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, asp.net-core, logic

How I can compress image without sacrificing its quality but i need to reduce the size whenever i copied compressed image to the another folder..?

string compressedFolderPath = @"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\VR Tasks\CompressiMG";
string compressedImagePath = Path.Combine(compressedFolderPath, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmssfff") + ".jpg");

```
             using (Image originalImage = Image.FromFile(imagePath))
             {
                 EncoderParameters encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(0);
                 encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, 50L);

                 ImageCodecInfo jpegCodec = GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg");

                 originalImage.Save(compressedImagePath, jpegCodec, encoderParameters);
             }

             return compressedImagePath;
```

But here quality is missing And also i have tried As Zipfile and Gzip File and Base64 as text file but size didn't reduced much.

Comment: If you don't want to lose any quality, you should go for a lossless compression algorithm. For example PNG format.

Comment: The image you’re trying to compress is already compressed, hence why zipping it doesn’t help much. If you want to retain the quality you’ll have to retain the size. You could try other lossless formats but the improvements are likely to be marginal at best.

Comment: You CANNOT compress without loosing quality. Thats the point. IF there was a compression mathod that decreased file size without damaging the Quality we would always be using it as default.

Comment: @DenisSchaf - sure you can compress without losing quality; that's what all the lossless compression formats do, and hence why we - mostly - all use PNG these days when we don't want loss.

Comment: If you want to reduce size without loosing quality, you may want to test the Webp format. Not supported directly in .NET, you need [LibWebp](https://github.com/imazen/libwebp-net) -- Lossless compression, even with complex images (photos), is better than lossy Jpeg compression and lossless PNG

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Thanks for your response but i need to retain the original image after compression is it possible is done and that I had used lossless compression but the size of the image does not change much. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Images have some amount of inherent information, or "quality". We sometimes call this [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)). However, in most images the actual entropy is smaller than the raw data size.

Lossless Compression methods like zip or png tries to reduce the file size as close to this theoretical limit, while retaining all the actual data exactly.

Lossy compression methods throw away data before the compression step. It tries to be smart about what data it throws away, but there is no way to get around the fact that you are throwing away data. Sooner or later you are going to notice a quality degradation. And if you are telling the jpeg encoder to use a low quality value you will almost certainly notice.

So your options are:

1. Accept a lower quality
2. Accept the larger file size
3. Use a smarter lossy compression algorithm. Jpeg is *old*, and there are many newer, better, algorithms that provide better subjective quality for a given file size. Here is a [comparison between a few newer formats](https://cloudinary.com/blog/how_jpeg_xl_compares_to_other_image_codecs). But do not expect any magic. You likely need to find appropriate libraries to encode and decode the images, since .net only include a basic set of encoders.

If you want to stick with jpeg you might want to experiment with lowering the resolution of your image. Jpeg does not handle high compression levels well, so you will likely get better results by reducing the resolution before compression.